# Локальный веб-сервер

Tags: pdo, сервер

Здравствуйте, товарищи. Долбил гугл с этим вопросом, но, увы

В общем, нужен локальный веб-сервер под окошки с поддержкой PDO. Посмотрел, open server и denwer этим пока не обзавелись, да и, судя по всему, не обзаведутся.

В общем, кто и что может посоветовать в этом вопросе? Или есть какой то выход прикрутить к денверу или open server желанное PDO?

Comment: **open server** уже имеет все необходимые расширения по умолчанию. Ничего даже выдумывать не нужно.

Comment: Расшифрую @mayar:

1. Вы можете поставить openserver, и будет вам PDO. Плюсы: минимум геморроя при установке, минусы: возможный геморрой из-за виндового окружения и окружения, фиксированного по правилам openserver
2. Вы можете поставить VirtualBox или Hyper-V (второй бы я не советовал до появления однозначной необходимости) и поставить виртуальную машину - debian, ubuntu или любой другой дистриб из зоопарка. Из минусов - настройка своими руками, из плюсов - вирутально-неограниченная гибкость, идентичность боевому серверу и куча опыта.

Comment: Я бы еще добавил. Если вы работаете с одним проектом, то безусловно и желательно поднимать свой сервер на VirtualBox. Кроме того, это будет неоценимый опыт лично для вас. Если же вы работаете с разными проектами, которые к тому же размещаются на серверах с разной конфигурацией расширений, то Open Server вам может очень пригодится. У меня есть проекты, у которых отличаются версии PHP, к тому же есть два полностью на Nginx,один на гибриде: Apache + Nginx и остальные просто на Апаче. В Open Server, я пару кликами меняю и версию PHP, и мускула, и могу ставить Nginx или Apache, или их гибрид.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Виртуалка-Линукс-Кайф : )

Или как-то так: http://open-server.ru/forum/search.php?keywords=pdo&terms=all&author=&sc=1&sf=all&sr=posts&sk=t&sd=d&st=0&ch=300&t=0&submit=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA